# Pushing a View Controller in a specific orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uideviceorientation

The main `UIViewController` (**A**) displays another `UIViewController` (**B**) when the devices rotates to Landscape mode. So rotating the device to landscape while on **A** presents **B** modally and rotating back to portrait on **B** dismisses **B** and goes back to **A**.

While on **B** I want to push another `UIViewController` (**C**) into **A**'s stack. **C**  can only be displayed in portrait though. I am aware that this goes against the HIG, as orientation should always be conserved between transitions.

So I want to be able to do the following on **B**:

- Dissmiss **B**
- Push **C** to **A**'s stack (so popping from **C** goes back to **A**)
- Switch back to portrait orientation so **C** is displayed in portrait

---

If you have the Pay With Square app, you'll see that they solved this problem by fading in **C** (rotate the app to show the map and choose an annotation) but they didn't add it to the current stack, allowing only dismiss it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah, this one is a little trickier :D

Answer (score 0):

You could push the view controller like normal then in viewDidAppear use some code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330979/how-to-set-device-ui-orientation-programmatically) thread to rotate the view.