# Forcing the portrait orientation for my View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

I am working on ARC based project. My project is targeted iOS 4.3 I want to force the

Portrait orientation to one of my view. The following doesn't seem to work for me.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Any help on this?

Comment: do you want to set orientation to only one view.. and rest others with  users choice..?

Comment: yea  exactly . I want to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the viewController to which orientations need to supported must implement the below method passing the supported orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

Later to manually rotate the view set the device orientation directly using

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

if this doesn't work use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
```

remember if you return NO for the setting orientation in `shouldAutoRotate` this may not work. Also check this in both ios5 & ios6, i have tried in ios5.

**EDIT:** For iOS5 or iOS6 where `setOrientation` doesn't exist

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:") withObject:(id)UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

this works fine, but this may be a private api now.

Comment: neither of the iOS its working.? have you tried both ways..? And one more thing the viewController is a presented one or pushed on a navigation stack.?

Comment: The view Controller is pushed to the navigation stack

Comment: does the rootViewController of the navigation stack support the orientation u r setting.?

Comment: check my edit, your orient methods was right.. where are u calling that method..? in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: I am calling it in ViewDidLoad and the method itself throws an error for me now

Comment: for non ARC that works, for others look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6 the last answer may help you..