# Incorrect Orientation of Views Inside Nested UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want all my views to be in Portrait mode. This works except when I push a `UINavigationController` onto another one. In this case the views inside the `secondaryNavigationController` will adhere to device orientation instead. Here is how I'm calling the `UINavigationControllers`.

```
[secondaryNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[[appDelegate secondaryNavigationController navigationBar] setHidden:YES];
[mainNavigationController presentModalViewController:[appDelegate secondaryNavigationController] animated:YES];
```

All my views implement this method but it doesn't seem to help.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: use this answer [UINavigationcontroller i cant stop rotation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333429/modal-uinavigationcontroller-i-cant-stop-rotation/13334446#13334446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full answer that worked for me, building off of iYaniv's comment and Jacky Boy's answer.

I took iYaniv's category and made it a subclass of `UINavigationController` instead of a category (which is what you should do). Then I replaced all instances of `UINavigationController *` with `myUINavigationController *`. Then used Jacky Boy's snippet in all of my `UIViewControllers`.

```
/* myUINavigationController.h */

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myUINavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

and

```
/* myUINavigationController.m */

#import "myUINavigationController.h"

@interface myUINavigationController ()

@end

@implementation myUINavigationController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Careful with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

[Since it has been deprecated on iOS 6.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:). At the moment here are some issues with the rotation of `UIViewControllers` inside `UINavigationControllers`, or `UITabBarControllers`. To solve this, in your case, you should either sub-class the `UINagivationController` or create a category for it (although Apple discourages the second one more than the first). You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504464/ios-6-uitabbarcontroller-supported-orientation-with-current-uinavigation-control) (this case is for a `UITabBarController`, but you can understand the logic), to check how to do the sub-classing. You can then do the following for your `UIViewControllers`:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Although you are allowing to rotate (returning YES), the `UIViewController` will always be in Portrait. The logic here is that if you are coming from a `UIViewController` that's on Landscape, if you were returning NO, your `UIViewController`, would stay in Landscape.