# IAD opened in a strange position in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I added an ADBannerView to my app. 
When rotated screen to landscape i change ADBannerView to horizontal frame like this:
[image]

But when it be clicked in iOS6, iad will open in a strange position:
[image]

in iOS4/5 don't have this problem.

Why and how to fix? I uploaded my code to https://github.com/OpenFibers/GPSAlarm

Special thanks!

Comment: This is Happening because due to the orientation issue , actually in IOS6 we need to Adjust the Orientation in different way as we did in prior to iOS6(in iOS5).so i would suggest you should manage your view as device orientation gets changed,can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023936/orientation-issue-in-ios-6/13024015#13024015

Comment: is your App Support multiple orientation...!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 6 there has been changes in UIKIT framework in your app delegate please use these codes to set your rootviewcontroller

```
if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
{
    //  addSubView doesn't work on iOS6
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationContoller;
}
else{
    // use this mehod on ios6
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigation];
}
```