# How can i handle UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown for UINavigationController in iPhone iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, orientation

I know that: By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom. So when I created a new project with Single View Application template, to perform all orientation in iPhone i add two method below to ViewController.m. And it work!

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then i changed some codes in method below of AppDelegate.m to change the root view of application from UIViewController to UINavigationController

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    if(myNavigationController == nil)
        myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.myNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

After that, i can't handle the UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown in iPhone iOS6 simulator. How can i resolve that? I tried to search a bit of code in older topic but it still not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orientation issue in ios 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023936/orientation-issue-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

Is `myNavigationController` a property? You reference it as `myNavigationController` and `self.myNAvigationController`. Seems inconsistant, especially since you initialize the object referencing the ivar, and then set the window's rootViewController with the property.

Also, you should clarify your question. I think you are asking how to get the iPhone to auto-rotate to upsidedown portrait. The answer is: Don't. The iPhone does not support horizontal rotation locking (un-like the iPad), and goes against design guidelines.

That being said: You may want to check that ALL of your viewControllers implement the rotation delegates, and that they ALL support upside-down rotation for iPhones. I know you said you started with a single-view application template, but there should be no other reason for the rotation being blocked.

Edit: Another thing you should check is your target settings. The "Supported Interface Orientation" section here may override your custom rotation code.