# iOS- Detect current size classes on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, size-classes

I'm working with adaptive Layout on iOS 8 and I want to get exactly what the size classes are on `viewDidLoad`. Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As of iOS 8 **UIViewController** adopts the **UITraitEnvironment** protocol. This protocol declares a property named **traitCollection** which is of type **UITraitCollection**. You can therefor access the **traitCollection** property simply by using `self.traitCollection`

**UITraitCollection** has two properties that you want to access named **horizontalSizeClass** and **verticalSizeClass** Accessing these properties return an **NSInteger**. The enum that defines the returned values is declared in official documentation as follows- *(this could potentially be added to in the future!)*

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass {
   UIUserInterfaceSizeClassUnspecified = 0,
   UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact     = 1,
   UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular     = 2,
};
```

So you could get the class and use say a switch to determine your code direction. An example could be -

```
NSInteger horizontalClass = self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass;
NSInteger verticalCass = self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass;

switch (horizontalClass) {
    case UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact :
        // horizontal is compact class.. do stuff...
        break;
    case UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular :
        // horizontal is regular class.. do stuff...
        break;
    default :
        // horizontal is unknown..
        break;
}
// continue similarly for verticalClass etc.
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Also noted that UIWindow implements UITraitCollection, so you can query the Size Class in your AppDelegate as well. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/

Comment: viewDidLoad is a bad place for doing size clas dependent stuff, as the size class might be unspecified, e.g. when the view does not yet have a superview. A better place is `viewWillLayoutSubViews` according to apple: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-233/?time=1263

Answer (score 20):

Some useful stuff for Swift 4:

UIViewController Extension to get the classes back as a Tuple.

```
extension UIViewController {
  func sizeClass() -> (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass) {
      return (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass, self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass)
  }
}
```

Example Switch statement to consume the function:

```
    switch self.sizeClass() {
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified):
        print("Unknown")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
        print("Unknown width, compact height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):
        print("Unknown width, regular height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified):
        print("Compact width, unknown height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified):
        print("Regular width, unknown height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
        print("Regular width, compact height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
        print("Compact width, compact height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):
        print("Regualr width, regular height")
    case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):
        print("Compact width, regular height")
    }
```

Edit/Addition:

If you are trying to access the trait collection early in the `UIViewController`'s lifecycle they might all be `UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.unspecified`.

This can be a pain if you happen to do constraints in code.

I recommend access the `.traitCollection` from the `UIScreen` shared object.

```
UIScreen.main.traitCollection
```

Or even more useful:

```
UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom
```

Comment: Nice, but cleaner if you remove all occurrences of 'UIUserInterfaceSizeClass' from your example.

Comment: UIScreen.main.traitCollection won't return the same size classes as your view controller in all circumstances though.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like that in Swift 5

```
enum DeviceTraitStatus {
    ///IPAD and others: Width: Regular, Height: Regular
    case wRhR
    ///Any IPHONE Portrait Width: Compact, Height: Regular
    case wChR
    ///IPHONE Plus/Max Landscape Width: Regular, Height: Compact
    case wRhC
    ///IPHONE landscape Width: Compact, Height: Compact
    case wChC

    static var current:DeviceTraitStatus{

        switch (UIScreen.main.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass, UIScreen.main.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass){

        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):      
            return .wRhR
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular):
            return .wChR
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.regular, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
            return .wRhC
        case (UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact, UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.compact):
            return .wChC
        default:
            return .wChR

        }

    }

}
```

The main advantatge is that can be used from not only a UIViewController class dependant and the static method can go into an i.e. Helper class. So you can do somewhere in your code:

```
let textSize:CGFloat = DeviceTraitStatus.current == .wRhR ? 18:14
```

Comment: A bit cleaner would be to put the traitStatus inside the enum as a static variable. No need for "MyHelper"...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Do you mean like that?

Comment: Perfect. Though if you want me to further nitpick I would recommend calling the classes wChC, wRhR, etc. to conform with the interface builder naming conventions... :)

Comment: @JorisWeimar Thank you again for your feedback. I wish the first time wasn't really bad. I put the old code in a iOS challenge...

Comment: Codereviews inside of stackoverflow I like it

Comment: FYI `macCatalyst` is Width: Regular, Height: Regular

Comment: @ReimondHill Your answer is very helpful and I gave it my up vote, and will attribute it in my code. There is only one issue with it, at least according to my needs. Having iPad OS (now 15) and current iPads, using `UIScreen.main.traitCollection` always gives `.regular` in both dimensions. This is not realistic when the app in in 1/2 split, 1/3 split, or slide over cases. So using `window?.traitCollection` (extracted from `AppDelegate`) gave me the right values according to how the app is located in the iPad screen.

Comment: I am glad it help @MostafaAlBelliehy This is a very old answer and not updated with the latest capabilities for iPad ... iPad is always regular Reg x Reg. You could extend the solution and use device orientation maybe too

Answer (score 3):

This is nice for testing/debugging:

```
let sizeClasses = ["Unspecified", "Compact", "Regular"]
print("SizeClass w:\(sizeClasses[traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass.rawValue]) h:\(sizeClasses[traitCollection.verticalSizeClass.rawValue])")
```

Answer (score -11):

So for Auto Layout you design your apps' UI per each different size class. The OS does all the work of figuring out the device being used and what size class should be used. However, if you there is a way to figure out what device is being used. I am not sure if you can decided what size class gets used as, again, this is handled dynamically by the OS.

Code for getting device being used:

```
NSString *device = [[UIDevice currentDevice]model ] ;
NSLog(@"%@",device);
```