# How to turn off device rotation programmatically - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to turn off the device rotation programmatically. I tried the below solution but this doesn't work for me.

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if shouldRotate == true {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: check these solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969419/ios-how-to-enable-and-disable-rotation-on-each-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your default rotation is .`portrait`. So in AppDelegate file, conform `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` then declare a property `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`, set it to `.portrait`.

```swift
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    ....
    var defaultRotation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return defaultRotation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method you mentioned is outdated. Instead, you should use the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in your view controller to control the [supported interface orientations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations).

Should look like this:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if shouldRotate {
        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .landscapeLeft
    }
}
```

Make sure you override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` property in the view controller where you want to control the rotation behavior. This will allow you to specify whether the view controller supports portrait or landscape orientations based on your `shouldRotate` flag.

Also, ensure that you have set the correct initial orientation settings for your app in your **project settings**. You can do this in Xcode by selecting your project, going to the "General" tab, and configuring the "Device Orientation" settings to match your desired behavior.

I hope I could help.

Comment: It shows an error - Property does not override any property from its superclass

Comment: Is your view controller class a subclass of `UIViewController`?