# How do I detect the interface or device orientation in a MessagesExtension app?

Tags: ios, swift

In order to set the `videoOrientation` of an `AVCaptureSession`, I need to know the current orientation the user is in (i.e. `portrait`, `landscapeLeft`, etc.).

- Using `UIDevice.current.orientation` always returns `unknown`, even when initiating device orientation changes with `UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()` and `UIDevice.current.isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` is returning `true`
- Apple has deprecated `interfaceOrientation` for the
  `UIViewController`.
- Trying `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` yields 1 Error and 1 Warning:

  - Error: `'shared' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.`
  - Warning: `'statusBarOrientation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the interfaceOrientation property of the window scene instead.`

There does not appear to be a window scene at all in Messages App Extensions.

Does anyone know how to detect the orientation from a Messages Extension? Ultimately I'm trying to re-create a camera view in landscape since `UIImagePickerController` does not support landscape for the Camera.

Comment: Its looks like here solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61749704

Comment: @Bimawa Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, Messages App Extensions don't have a window scene at all from what I can tell.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37329460/887325