# Get the current device orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uidevice

I know that this question was asked before and tried to implement the suggested solution, but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps I am doing smth wrong. Do you have any idea?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    test.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon

    func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            test.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        } else {
            test.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current orientation of device programatically in iOS 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836578/how-to-get-current-orientation-of-device-programatically-in-ios-6)

Comment: I tried to follow these suggestions but could not implement them in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nested functions - that won't work. Change it to this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon
}
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        test.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    } else {
        test.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

In fact, you can get rid of the override for viewWillLayoutSubviews with the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

** to those that need additional help see recommendations below
** this function will be called before the change in size and but you will know it from the arguments

**Swift 3.x +**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        //Landscape

            print("before transition")
            print("w "+"\(width)")
            print("h "+"\(height)")
            print("to size")
            print("w "+"\(size.width)")
            print("h "+"\(size.height)")

    } else {
        //Portrait      

            print("before transition")
            print("w "+"\(width)")
            print("h "+"\(height)")
            print("to size")
            print("w "+"\(size.width)")
            print("h "+"\(size.height)")

    }

}
```