# Where are the methods that defines allowed orientations?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I've been working on my app for a while, and it've been out in appStore for a while as well, but I now want to add support for landscape orientation. I've thought I had just unchecked the orientation-icons in the Summary-page of the target to only enable portrait, but when I check them now, nothing happens! A lot of stash has been added, but I can't find any methods that should disable landscape.. What kind of method would that be? I didn't find anything in appDelegate either.. I don't even know where to start looking.. When opening an empty project in xcode, they orient just fine with no methods at all..

In storyboard, when clicking a view and going to inspector, it says Orientation:Inferred. So the problem isn't here.
I using a tabBar, and all the views in the viewControllers are set to `Autoresize subviews`, as a similar question got answered.

**EDIT**

When enabling landscape for iPhone using the buttons in the target properties summary, the iPhone is allowed to go landscape, but when enabling it for the iPad, nothing changes..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651309/1059705 this link may help you in iOS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making a class for the UITabBarController, and setting shouldAutorotate... to YES. I find it weird though that my iPad storyboard overrode the Summary-page.

**EDIT**

This is giving me a hard time with everything else.. The device rotates correctly now, but sometimes when launched in landscape, it thinks it's in portrait.. Still trying to figure that out. Even when I ask the app which orientation the devices statusbar is in, it returns portrait even if it really is in landscape..

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotate` in iOS6 and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for previous version.
Note that the orientation is mostly defined by the ViewController.

Comment: Yes, I added this method to one of my views, and it gets called, but nothing happens except for the NSLog I put in there. I also tried `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, it doesn't get called.

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` ?

Comment: In the Summary-page in target, they are all checked, I also checked in the plist that they are all added correctly. I guess that means the same thing, but still, I can't find where it says it shouldn't orient to landscape.. And no, I haven't locked my device to one portrait.

Comment: And no, if that's a method, it's not used in either the viewController nor the app delegate.

Comment: `-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

Answer (score 0):

you can add or remove the supported orientations in info.plist

[image]

Comment: Yes, as I said in the comment to Larme, I've already verified the plist.. Sadly they are not the problem..