# How change orientations programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation

How to change orientation programmatically. when  button action is performed?
 I tried below code but is showing some error called "no visible interface for uidevice declares the selector setorientation"

my code is

```
       if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
    // code for landscape orientation
    // OR
   //        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    //        //  OR
 /  /        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

}
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12650730/1011213)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6/12650730#12650730