# About using setOrientation in iOS sdk 6.1

Tags: ios, webview, setorientation

I am working on a project based on **phonegap** iOS. And we load web site pages and local html pages in the same `webview`. When load some page ,the view will be portrait ,and some of these pages are landscape,the others will support  both landscape and portrait .Now when I try :

```
[UIDevice currentDevice]  setOrientation: UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

An error occured : `No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'setOrientation:'`
Is this about the version of sdk or something else ? I saw other people can use it and just get a waring on the stackoverflow.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 `setOrientation` is depreciated, you should replace it with:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

check below question for more details:

[How to change the device orientation programmatically in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS6, the '[orientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation)' property of UIDevice is 'readonly'.

To control the interface orientations in iOS6, you can refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW3) Apple doc.