# UIViewController orientation setting

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

Hi i am new to ios development...

I have created on project that supports for only landscape only.For that i used like this [image: settings image]

But when i am going to print view sizes

```
  NSLog(@"%f--%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
```

in log it giving

```
   768.000000--1024.000000
```

instead of

```
 1024.000000--768.000000
```

And also i added a code

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
          {
         BOOL res=((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)||       (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
return res;
        }
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.Please help me on this

Comment: SO has loads of answers for this very question. See this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6

Comment: I am using xcode5 and ios7.0.In that it showing error 'No Visible @Interface for  [UIDevice] setOrientation:'   How to achieve this....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime even setting like this fail check solution

In the properties file for your app (YOURAPPNAME-Info.plist), 
There is an array called "Supported interface orientations". 
Remove the orientations you don't want from the array, and your app will be locked into the remaining orientation.

In iOS 6 setOrientation is depreciated, you should replace it with:

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

and return true only for landscapes in orientation methods