# How to rotate orientation programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I tried the next:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

on

```
viewWillAppear
```

but it does not work. How can I rotate my screen on viewWillAppear?

**UPDATE**

I use the next code for locking an orientation:

```
var shouldRotate = true
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if shouldRotate == true {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue)
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
  private func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
        if shouldRotate == true {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft.rawValue)
        }
    }
```

and in my FIRST controller in viewWillAppear I set:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = true
}
```

in my SECOND controller:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = false
}
```

so, when I back from SECOND controller to the FIRST:

I rotate it to left - does not rotate, rotate back to right - nothing, rotate to left, again - it rotates.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 43):

**To change orientation programatically in swift 3**, use the following way:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

You can use the orientations,

**1. portrait
2. portraitUpsideDown
3. landscapeLeft
4. landscapeRight**

Comment: Isn't this unsafe? What if Apple decides to change "orientation" one day?

Comment: @XavierL. according to apple documentation, this is one of the method to change the orientation of device. for more details check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation

Comment: @XavierL. So we can change it when Apple decides to change it.

Comment: Love this answer. Because I searched all day and all other solutions regarding this problem was not working.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4:**

[image]

**Step1:**

In Appdelegate - Declare `deviceOrientation` var which is `portrait` by default

```
import UIKit
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var deviceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return deviceOrientation
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

In your certain ViewController write this to change orientation -

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     appDelegate.deviceOrientation = .landscapeLeft
     let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
     UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `UIViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations()` instead of triggering rotation in `viewWillAppear`

For Xcode 7

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```

For Xcode 6

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
}
```

And make sure the desired orientations are enabled in project settings.

[image]

Comment: it gives me the next error: ` Overriding method with selector 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' has incompatible type '() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask'`

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` is not convertible to Int error

Comment: try `return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)`

Comment: it works, but crashes with `terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [myapp.SecondViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'`

Comment: try `return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue`

Comment: And make sure you enable landscape in App level

Comment: I have used Portrait, not LandscapeLeft and yes, I'm sure that these orientations are enable

Comment: I think **Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application** means that the orientation you set in ViewController is not available in App Level.

Comment: These orientations support in my app level, be sure. I checked checkbox of these orientations

Answer (score 2):

### Edit:

Can modify this to implement any combination of orientations.

## In AppDelegate:

```
internal var viewControllerOrientation = 0
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if viewControllerOrientation == 0 {
        return .portrait
    } else if viewControllerOrientation == 1 {
      return .landscapeLeft
    } else if viewControllerOrientation == 2 {
      return .landscapeRight
    }
}
```

## LandscapeLeftViewController

View controller is locked in landscapeLeft orientation

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.viewControllerOrientation = 1
}

@IBAction func newVCBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.viewControllerOrientation = 0

    // go to different view controller method, such as:
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

## LandscapeRightViewController

View controller is locked in landscapeRight orientation

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.viewControllerOrientation = 2
}

@IBAction func newVCBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.viewControllerOrientation = 0

    // go to different view controller method, such as:
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

All other view controllers are locked in portrait orientation. Again, can modify this to implement any combination of locked orientations you want.

Answer (score 2):

swift 5

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    class func setUIInterfaceOrientation(_ value: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```