# UIDevice set orientation not working on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uideviceorientation

What I'm trying to achieve is that when user presses a button, to programmatically simulate device rotation to landscape.
I've this code that is working for iPhone devices but not for iPads

```swift
let value = NSNumber(integerLiteral: UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue)
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
ViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

Is there a way to achieve the same on iPads?

Comment: You are right.  You have my blessing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345409/how-to-rotate-orientation-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: @zaitsman  That topic won't help in changing the orientation when you have an iPad.

Comment: @ElTomato how do you mean? you really can't change the orientation of the OS. but you can restrict which orientations your app recognises, and you can do so based on absolutely anything (programmatically), like day of the week or time of day, or userInterfaceIdiom

Comment: @zaitsman What is "the orientation of the OS"?  I am saying that you can change the orientation with `UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")` if you have an iPhone.  But the same scheme does not work if you do it with an iPad.

Comment: @zaitsman the question you post actually has pretty much this code as the most accepted answer (I probably took it from there). But as El Tomato says my problem is that it does not work on iPads. And I can’t find a reference to that particular issue in that question. Thought there could be some workaround to make it work but it seems not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the *direct* solution to this is pretty simple but it has a drawback. It is fixed by setting **Requires Full Screen** to true in the project settings General section. Of course, this means your app won't support multitasking, which may not be suitable depending on your app.

[image]

Comment: not worked for me. It still not work on iPadOS 14.

Answer (score -1):

How do you detect changes in device orientation? If you use

```
func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

to detect, then it won't be called on iPad. You can use this instead

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in
        let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
        if orient.isPortrait {
            // portrait now
        } else if orient.isLandscape {
            // landscape now
        }
    }, completion: nil)
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```