# How To Programmatically Create Device Orientation Detection Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, device-orientation

I am trying to create my `iOS` application completely programmatic without using `storyboard`. Now I am struggling for different device orientation `Identification`. I did separate UI sizes by using device height but I need to create for `landscape` orientation different sizes, For me by using below code I cant handle device orientation.

My Code Below :

```
   // Device difrrentiate
    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && ((UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)))) {

        // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (result.height == 480) {

    // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPhone 3G & 3GS & 4 & 4S
        }
        if (result.height == 568) {

    // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPhone 5, 5C & 5S
        }
        if (result.height == 667) {

    // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPhone 6
        }
        if (result.height == 736) {

           // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPhone 6 Plus
        }
       }
       } else if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) && ((UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)))) {

        // The device is an iPad and iPad mini running iOS 3.2 or later.
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (result.height == 1024) {

        // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPad, iPad 2, iPad Mini
        }
        if (result.height == 2048) {

         // Here I can declare the UI sizes for iPad Air, iPad Mini Retina
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the device orientation programmatically in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6)

Comment: without giving clear answer dont put duplicate possiblilty. Before post my question I tried everything still I am not solviong my problem. Please understand to remove duplicate from my post @Badal Shah

Comment: you can find your answer in this Answer on that link. Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12651309/4910767.

Comment: I will give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For landscape this should work:

```
if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
```

Check this:

```
    @interface ViewController ()
    {
        UIButton *btn;
        UIView *vw;
    }
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    vw=[[UIView alloc]init];

    btn.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 40);
    vw.frame=CGRectMake(100, 360, 150, 100);

    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    vw.backgroundColor=[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [self.view addSubview:vw];
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        //in landscape width=480 height=300. statusbar Height=20 by default
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(150, 60, 60, 40);
        vw.frame=CGRectMake(150, 200, 150, 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //in portrait width=320 height=460. statusbar Height=20 by default
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 40);
        vw.frame=CGRectMake(100, 360, 150, 100);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Previously I've written frames only for 4s. Please check edited answer again. It works fine for me.

Comment: Ok @Satish. I will check again and let you know. Thank!

Comment: whats the issue in it @Apple_Ajay