# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification is returning UIOrientationLandscapeLeft for UIOrientationLandscapeRight

Tags: iphone, notifications, orientation, ios6

I am registering  my viewcontroller for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification and it's return wrong orientation of device.
I am registering it in init function of viewcontroller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handleOrientationChangeNotification:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];
```

This is my device Notification Receiver method.

```
-(void)handleOrientationChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{ 
    if(IS_IPHONE)
    {
        UIDeviceOrientation currentDeviceOrientation =  [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Whenever Device Orientation changed,I am always getting wrong orientation.

Comment: This might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330979/how-to-set-device-ui-orientation-programmatically

Comment: the code seems to be fine & working.. have you unchecked auto layout in xib..?

Comment: probably this is happening because apple has changed it's orientation way in iOS6 as apple was doing in past versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution on apple site on this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIInterfaceOrientation)

`UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` is assigned to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` and `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft` is assigned to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. the reason for this is that rotating the device requires rotating the content in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is Probably happening because Apple Has changed the Way of managing the Orientation of UIViewController.
In Ios6 Oreintation handles Differently,  in `iOS6 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method has deprecated.iOS containers (such as `UINavigationController`) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` for the iPad idiom and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown` for the iPhone idiom.

[For More Information regarding the same You should visit this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166)
Below I have made the Category for handling the Orientation Change.

SO You will have to implement the Two more methods for managing the Orientation of UIViewController in iOS6.

Introduced In IOS6 Allow Orientation Change

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
  {

    return YES;

  }
```

Return the Number of Oreintation going to supported in device

```
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

 }
```

Now check what orientation you are getting.

EDIT: Place this Code to your FirstViewController added as root ViewController .this will help the UIViewController to determine it's Orientation.

```
@implementation UINavigationController (RotationIn_IOS6)

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
  {
   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
  }

  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

 - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
 {
   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
 }

 @end
```

I hope i'll be  helpful to  you.

Comment: Thanks @Kamarshad. but actually orientation functions had nothing to do with my code. However i found the solution and posted it as an answered my question