# ViewController and SubView are not rotating correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, orientation

I am working on a landscape view for a currently existing application.  I believe I have autoRotate, supported interface, etc set up correctly, I am actually reusing code that works with a much simpler app.  However when the simulator is rotated into landscape mode, the correct view loads, but the status bar and view stay with the short edge of the iPad.  I've attached a screenshot and code.  Is the problem with a view controller higher up in the chain, or the appdelegate?  I've traced the called controllers in the debugger and it appears they are dismissed once this page is loaded.  I am fairly new-ish to obj-c so it is possible this is something simple I am missing, but I have checked all attributes for the .xib file and everything looks copasetic.
[image]
Some of the code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;// | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return NO;
}![enter image description here][2]

-(void)orientationChanged{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];  

    if ((interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)||(interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){
        self.view = self.portraitView;
    } else {
        self.view = self.landscapeView;
    }
}
```

EDITS - This problem occurs on both iOS 7.1 and 6.1 and this is the first time any screen in the app supports a landscape view.  To clarify the views, the portrait and landscape views are separate Views in single .xib file.  The file owner class is set to the correct view controller class, and the parent view controller, a sales screen, should not rotate.  It does not have a landscape view, but even with its autoRotate methods set to return YES the subview does not orient correctly.

Comment: Maybe you should change the `NO` in your `shouldAutorotate` methods to `YES`.

Comment: So the root viewcontroller does not support rotation only the view inside it? I think the root viewcontroller needs to support rotation in order to receive these events. You have to work from the ground up. First your root view controller needs to start receiving the events, so disregard what you want to end up with and start with that. Then try to route your call to the view code of that xib. If that works try to prevent the parent from rotating. But to be honest, rotation support is not something you can bolt on easily as an afterthought.

Comment: I've added orientation notifications to every view class and have NSLog printing out every time the orientation changed method is called.  Using that I've IDed the two view controllers higher up the chain than the customers screen.  I've set them to autoRotate and to accept all orientations, but the problem is still remaining.  I'm fairly certain it is as you said @DepartamentoB that the landscape view can not be bolted on as needed, without the app being configured properly and the start.  So more than likely my new project will be to rebuild the views from the ground up.

Comment: Does the root view controller receive orientation changes or not? That's the one that should handle all rotation based events. The other View Controllers aren't supporting rotation because they're not root view controllers, so anything you set up there for rotation is **completely ignored**. You should call methods manually on them from the rotation that is being received by the root view controller.

Comment: The flow of controllers is a splash screen that informs loading time from DB, then a sales screen with table map and info, then selecting a customer from the table brings up the customer screen - this screen needs a landscape view-all of the screens receive the orientation notification and but only the splash and sales screen rotate correctly but not the customer screen.  The appDelegate sets the splash screen as the rootViewController at launch, once it is done calculating DB download it pushes the sales screen.

Answer (score 0):

Like 0x7ffffffff already said you need to allow rotation in your shouldAutorotate functions. Also you need to set up the supported rotation directions in your project setup.

First go to your project's settings:

[image: Go to settings]

Next you need to select all the orientations you want to support:

[image: Part of project settings]

Another that is very important: ONLY the root View Controller will receive rotation events. If you nest a View Controller inside a View Controller then that nested Controller will not receive those events unless you wire them up manually from the parent. That's why I usually don't nest ViewControllers but use ad-hoc NSObjects or UIView implementations for nested views.

Last but not least: make sure your device is not rotation-locked: http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/972915

Comment: setting autoRotate to YES doesn't change anything.  My thinking was with autoRotate being NO, I don't want the buttons/labels to autoRotate, this needs to load a separate view from the .xib file.  Having it set to NO in my other app works perfectly, that's why I'm thinking this is a problem with a view controller further up the hierarchy.  Also changing the device orientation in the deployment info doesn't fix it either, furthermore not all the views, several dozen of them, don't support anything but portrait, making any universal changes then would be no bueno.

Comment: Further up the hierarchy? The only ViewController that receives rotation events is the root ViewController, the rest doesn't respond to that. You have to wire up your child ViewControllers manually on those events. I have edited my answer with some new information about nested ViewControllers.

Comment: the method orientationChanged is being called from NSNotifcationCenter (I believe anyway) and it is within this secondaryView controller.  Should orientationChagned be placed in RootViewController, have it orient there, then somehow send a message to secondaryView to load the correct view?  I set up some NSLog in both secondaryView and RootViewController and the only calls being printed are in secondaryView.  Or does that relate to correctly wiring up the secondaryView to RootViewController?

Comment: Perhaps you could update your post a little bit with the following: 

1. Schema of how you nested your controllers.
2. What could you put where do do what.

You should not call those rotation methods inside a viewcontroller that is nested inside another viewcontroller. Also I noticed the top bar is sideways in your screenshot. That only happens if an orientation is not supported. I would suggest that you take the nested viewcontroller out for a while and concentrate on getting very basic rotation going in your main viewcontroller because I think it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: The controllers seem to start with a rootViewController, when the app launches a splash screen starts, it is then dismissed after some check (like syncing to the database) then the primary sales screen appears.  This screen is the parent of the view that I am trying to rotate.  After setting up the NSNotificaitonOrientationDidChange for this parent class, I saw on the NSLog that it is called every time the orientation is changed.  However, setting autoRotate and shouldAutoRotate.. to YES causes several problems.  Namely the main sales screen rotates now, which it shouldn't.......

Comment: ...and the startup splash screen is rotating on loading, and at times the sales screen is upside down and will not reorient correctly.  I've managed to get the status bar in the correct location by manually setting it in the orientationChaged call in the parent(sales screen) controller.  The subview still does not orient correctly.  It may not be the best solution, but if I can rotate the view by 90 degrees on orientation loading that would "fix" the issue.  Just FYI this is my first project at this job, no one has implemented a landscape view like this before, so I'm pretty much on my own.

Comment: Some of the earlier design could have been better optimized to allow for easier control of the different views, but the app itself is a few years old and has to run on devices spanning back to iOS 4.  So reconfiguring the appDelegate to play nicer would be a great idea, but at this point just isnt practical.

Comment: It sounds a lot like this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889991/uideviceorientationdidchangenotification-is-returning-uiorientationlandscapeleft are you having these problems also on older versions of the simulator? shouldAutorotate is deprecated for a while https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: - this is the first time this app will support rotation? Please update your original question for others

Comment: Added updates to your questions, thanks for the help so far.  I'm starting to feel that this issue is steaming from the initial pushViewController from the appDelegate and the splash screen and sales screen fighting for rootViewControl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring because a subclass of the customerView was not receiving the rotation notification.  After tracking that class down it was a matter of setting up the NSNotificationCenter for orientation changes and then allowing autoRotation and supprotedInterfaceOrientations.