# Change the device orientation programmatically swift 4 IOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to restrict some views of my App to Landscape.How can I achieve this functionality.Is this possible according Apple Guidelines.

Comment: I specifically asked about swift 4 and IOS 11 and the duplication you considered is deprecated.Remove the duplicate from the question so I can share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail its hard to say if this will solve your problem, but heres a link to a fix for a similar sounding problem. [Force Landscape on View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660334/6430945)