# LibGDX on iOS: Rotate screen programmatically using Robovm

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I have a problem that i've mentioned in title.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27037839/7717409) It does in ViewController in ViewDidAppear.
But how to import this piece of code to java and where to call it if **i want to change rotation after some point of the game.**

I tried to do something like this:

```
long landscapeOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.value();
UIDevice.getCurrentDevice().getKeyValueCoder().setValue("orientation", landscapeOrientation);
```

Stuck since i need NSObject...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to *Demyan Kimitsa* from [Robovm's gitter](https://gitter.im/MobiVM/robovm).

```
long landscapeOrientation =  UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.value();
UIDevice.getCurrentDevice().getKeyValueCoder().setValue("orientation", NSNumber.valueOf((int) landscapeOrientation));
```