# How do I programmatically control device orientation's effects?

Tags: ios, swiftui

**Scenario:** I set the default device orientation to portrait.  However, there are some Views that I want to allow for landscape mode.

Most of my views don't need to be in landscape.  But there are some with orientation detection that allows a full-size linear graph to be displayed in landscape mode.

I want my application to behave as a Portrait-Centric for most of the time.

**Question:** How do I freeze the Portrait when I need to, but allow for Landscape when the situation warrants it?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually allow, and most importantly in your case, disallow device orientation through `UIInterfaceOrientation`. Full description was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859280/13296047

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28238151)

Comment: The link references UIKit.   I'm using SwiftUI.
I'm going to try to work with it.
Thanks.

Comment: @koen: This wouldn’t normally qualify as a link-only answer. The contributor suggests this can be accomplished using `UIInterfaceOrientation`. The link offers additional details.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not Yet.  So far, I can handle orientation if I don't use the navigator.  The Navigator View screws things up.  So If I don't find a suitable solution, I'll mimic the navigator with a simpler 'flat' View.