# ios disable/enable rotation during view excecution

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

I want to know how to disable/enable rotation during view life.
Is there a way to update shouldAutorotate in the view life(without reloading the view)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple Docs :

- shouldAutorotate
  Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller's contents should auto rotate.

Declaration
SWIFT
func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool

OBJECTIVE-C
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

More on this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate

You should add this to the method where you decide if the user can rotate or not of your ViewController :

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

See also : [Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

Comment: I agree with you but, i want by default the view rotate, and for example, if a popup appears the view can't rotate until this popup desappear. Any idea?