# I want only one screen in portrait mode while all other in both landscape and portrait mode ios 9 application

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I want to Restrict one page in portrait orientation while whole application in both landscape and portrait orientation how to achieve this functionality. I have tried old code from stack over flow but it's not working.

If any one solved such problem then please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ... add the code which is not working and provide the steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

Comment: There are DOZENS of SO answers on this... and they should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this snippet to the ViewController which should not rotate:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, But I have already tried that but it's not working.