# How to change UIWebView orientation programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3

I've created UIWebView programmatically. Now i want to set programmatically its orientation to (landscape or portrait).
Please can anyone tell me how i can do this?
Thanks

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
        webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://tune.tv/humtv-live-embed")!))
        webV.delegate = self;
        self.view.addSubview(webV)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios

Comment: Thanks but i just want to change orientation of UIWebView not of Whole ViewController class. Because i have to use UIWebView in CollectionVIew Class for cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your viewDidAppear add the following:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Just choose your orientation and it will be set to it when the WebView is shown.

Comment: I just want to change orientation of UIWebView not of Whole ViewController class. Because i have to use UIWebView in CollectionVIew Class for cells.
And when i run first time my project after adding that code in my class it show in landscape but when i change it to portrait by using Command and right arrow.  and then again run my project it not show in landscape mode?

Comment: I don´t think it´s possible to achieve what you´re trying to do. You can only change the orientation for the entire view as I showed in my example. If you need further help do tell me.

Comment: For example in this Project i just want to change orientation of UIWebView to landscape when it loads and when i exit UIWebView then collectionView Show in portrait?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxLTJWVXJTS3FQSFU

Comment: Just move the webView to a new viewController and control it that way. I updated your project with that functionality. Download a new version at this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvoeddliwstzn7q/videoPlay.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you very much Rashwan L.
Now its working as i want.
And i replace this line 

cell.playBt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.webView(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

with this 

cell.playBt.addTarget(self, action: Selector("webView:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

And works (y)