# Changing orientations programmatically does not work fine

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

My whole application is in `portrait` mode. I just want to use one view controller in `landscape` mode (left).

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask 
{
    if let _navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

        if _navigationController.topViewController is FullScreenPlayerVC {

            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

This is my controller A

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Now i push Controller B. This is my controller B

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
 }

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```

It works as per my requirement when i push controller B while holding my device in portrait mode but if i am holding my phone in landscape left already.

It does not perform desired action. Searched a lot about it but not able to find the solution yet.

I have tried many solutions but nothings working fine.

Comment: just use below code , no need for DidAppear inside code .   override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      return .Landscape
    }

Comment: tried this but was useful unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic solution for your problem and others related.

**1. Create auxiliar class UIHelper and put on the following methods:**

```
    /**This method returns top view controller in application  */
    class func topViewController() -> UIViewController?
    {
        let helper = UIHelper()
        return helper.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)
    }

    /**This is a recursive method to select the top View Controller in a app, either with TabBarController or not */
    private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController:UIViewController?) -> UIViewController?
    {
        if(rootViewController != nil)
        {
            // UITabBarController
            if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
                let selectedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController {
                return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: selectedViewController)
            }

            // UINavigationController
            if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController ,let visibleViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController {
                return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: visibleViewController)
            }

            if ((rootViewController!.presentedViewController) != nil) {
                let presentedViewController = rootViewController!.presentedViewController;
                return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: presentedViewController!);
            }else
            {
                return rootViewController
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
```

**2. Create a Protocol with your desire behavior, for your specific case will be landscape.**

protocol orientationIsOnlyLandscape {}

Nota: If you want, add it in the top of UIHelper Class.

**3. Extend your View Controller**

In your case:

```
class B_ViewController: UIViewController,orientationIsOnlyLandscape {

   ....

}
```

**4. In app delegate class add this method:**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let presentedViewController = UIHelper.topViewController()
        if presentedViewController is orientationIsOnlyLandscape {
            return .landscape
        }
        return .portrait
    }
```

**Final Notes:**

- If you that more class are in landscape mode, just extend that
  protocol.
- If you want others behaviors from view controllers, create other protocols and follow the same structure.
- This example solves the problem with orientations changes after push
  view controllers