# How to stop or disable portrait/auto rotate app in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How to disable portrait orientation in swift 3?

```
 xcode 8 and swift 3
```

Comment: you can disable that in general tab of your project.

Comment: @KKRocks thanks, its working fine after disable in general tab of project.

Comment: solved your problem ?

Comment: yes, its solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

**By User Interface**
[image]

**Programatically**

Add this in appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape.rawValue)
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply `return .landscape` or `return [.landscape] ` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in the general tab of your application that will allow you to disable/enable different orientations.

Comment: Strangely, this seems to just not work from Xcode 13 on .... you have to use the code.  Strange.