# tabbar controller in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

I am working on a project in which I need to have the application in landscape mode. I made the changes in .plist file by setting interface orientation to landscape. I changed the orientation to landscape in the .xib files also but still when the application starts the in the simulator the tabbar controller appears in portrait mode only. Can any one please help with this.

Thanks

Comment: I think that was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by design, the `UITabBarController` will only rotate to support an interface orientation that *all* of its view controllers support. It will send the `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` message to each of its view controllers and, if they all return `YES`, will return `YES`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I missed to set return to one of the view controller.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me. I only had the problem on generation 1 iPad that was running iOS5. On simulator/iOS6/newer devices it was working even when one of my UITabBarController's view controller did not have it's own implementation of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.