# How to set device orientation programmatically in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a ebook reader app where in, i need to programmatically adjust the device orientation according to the layout of the page... i.e, The device should support all orientations for some pages and only landscape for some other pages. Is there anyway in which i can force a orientation change programatically

Comment: How about `setStatusBarOrientation:animated` in UIApplication ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer from jbat100 plus a call to `setStatusBarOrientation:animated` in UIApplication to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the behavior for this has changed as of iOS 6.0. For further info, see: [Autorotate  in iOS 6 has strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour)

The gist is that should/will/did/etc have been deprecated and have been replaced with a cleaner, more dynamic implementation. Which we should all be thankful for.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

This can set the device orientation to LandscapeRight programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the device orientation to some value, the system tells you the device's orientation, not the opposite. You can rotate your views using `CGAffineTransform` and such (a related post [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3219-force-landscape-mode-one-view-2.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can force any rotation. At least I was able to do it. Solution I used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146270/894671

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Xcode 6 & 5.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return YES;}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);}
```