# iOS 6 MPMoviePlayerViewController and presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated Rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, iphone-5

In previous iOS versions, our video would rotate automatically but in iOS 6 this is no longer the case. I know that the presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated was designed to do that before but how can I tell the MPMoviePlayerViewController to rotate automatically?

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

Comment: Possible dup to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour. Actually that question and answers talks about this problem well.

Answer (score 10):

In appdelegate.m :

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if ([[self.window.subviews.lastObject class].description isEqualToString:@"MPMovieView"]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Kinda a hack, but works well...

Comment: *sidenote:* this is for iOS 6+ . For iOS 5 or below, use codes similar to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`

Comment: When I start a movie I get back as an description; 'UITransitionView' Why is this? it's the same name as my view controllers are returning

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same problem. James Chen's solution is correct, but I ended up doing something a little simpler that also works - overriding application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in my app delegate and returning allButUpsideDown if my rootView controller was modally presenting an MPMoviePlayerViewController. Admittedly a hack, and may not be appropriate to all situations, but saved me having to change all my view controllers:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return [rootViewController.modalViewController isKindOfClass:MPMoviePlayerViewController.class ] ? UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll : UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, first thanks for answering. You have solved my same MPMoviePlayerViewController rotation issue But while i dissmiss the moviePlayer, still i am getting MPMoviePlayerViewController in rootViewController.modalViewController. I tried : [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and [movieController dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];

Answer (score 4):

This is not limited to `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. From iOS 6 the autorotation has been changed. see [Autorotate  in iOS 6 has strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour) .

To make your app behave as pre-iOS 6, you have to make the app support all orientations (edit `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` in plist), then for all other view controllers which don't support rotation, override this method to return NO:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

By default `MPMoviePlayerViewController` supports all orientations so this should be enough to make it work.

Comment: I changed my plist file to allow all orientations yet it affects nothing. My app still remains in portrait mode no matter the orientation. I searched high and low through code to see if something is blocking rotation but I see nothing. Any ideas.

Comment: @JamesChen this is it! so simple, saved me hours digging!