# Getting a reference to the MPMoviePlayerController on user touch

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I currently have an `MPMoviePlayerController` with `controlStyle` set to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`.

When the video finishes playing, I want to allow the user to replay the video by touching the video.

I have set a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view which is correctly calling an event handler when a `MPMoviePlayerController` is tapped.

However, I can only seem to obtain the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view through the `UITapGestureRecognizer` that is passed to the event handler so I can't access the actual `MPMoviePlayerController` object to play the video again.

I'm very new to iOS and objective-c development so this may be a silly question. Is there a way I can get a reference to the `MPMoviePlayerController` to start playing it again?

Here is the code used to set up the UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleMoviePlayerTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.delegate = self;
[_moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Here is the handler with nothing implemented yet:

```
- (void)handleMoviePlayerTap :(UITapGestureRecognizer*) tap
{
    NSLog(@"Movie player was tapped");
    // Somehow start playing the video again
}
```

Comment: don't add it to `_moviePlayer.view` .. add it to its parent view.

Comment: I have a UITapGestureRecognizer for the parent view that I want to handle differently.

Comment: ok i though `_moviePlayer` is `MPMoviePlayerController` ..
depends upon how your are adding `MPMoviePlayerController` .. please check 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593542/ios-6-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-and-presentmovieplayerviewcontrolleranimated-r)

Comment: _moviePlayer is my MPMoviePlayerController. Not sure how that link relates. Thanks

Comment: declare `_moviePlayer` globally .. this way you can call `[_moviePlayer play]` in `handleMoviePlayerTap` ..

Comment: I have a lot of `MPMoviePlayerController`'s on the screen so need to get a reference to the correct one. I think I will just resort to checking the position of the touch and see which `MPMoviePlayerController` it is in the bounds of. Thanks

Comment: i don't think there is way to get `MPMoviePlayerController` from its child view `MPMovieView`  . you can make a invisible view on each `MPMoviePlayerController` and add tap . make use of `.tag` as a difference for each invisible view.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an `NSMutableDictionary` to map from the view to the `MPMoviePlayerController`.