# iPhone 5 app rotating when it shouldn't (only on app store)

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an app that shouldn't rotate unless on one particular screen.

The problem is that it is rotating on all screens, but the real big problem is that it only occurs when the users download the app from **app store** and are using it on **iPhone 5**, so I can't really find a way to test and fix the bug, since I wasn't able to reproduce it (in a development environment) so far.

I believe this is not an iOS problem since other devices with the same version are doing ok with the version I uploaded to apple through XCode, the bug really only occur when downloaded from app store and is installed on iPhone 5.

Any thoughts on what might be happening or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you implementing `shouldn't rotate unless on one particular screen`?

Comment: Are you sure the code hasn't changed since release? If you still have an ipa file from release, or pre-release, I'd be installing it to check.

Comment: @AndreiG. I did it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12628031/842715)

Comment: @user352891 yes, I'm sure it didn't changed