# Application Lauch in Landscape mode while Simulator/Device is in Portrait mode in ios6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, orientation, device-orientation

My application window has `UITabBarController` as a `RootViewController`. Then `UINavigationController` as `TabBarController's` `RootViewController`. Then another `HomeViewController` as `NavigationController'`s `RootViewController`.

When I launch my application in `Portrait` mode, then HomeViewController's `UIView` outlets displayed in `Landscape` mode. All `UIView` outlets have Landscape mode coordinate. Because return Orientation is `Landscape`.

I found many Q&A, Blogs. I applied whatever other developers said, but not succeed.

This issue occurs only in ios6 device/iPhone simulator 6.

Right now I am working on Simulator and its show this issue.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Ask me, if I am not capable to explain my question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6, the app looks at your predefined possible orientations from your project file. Check if that only lists landscape, also it uses the  shouldAutoRotate method, so you might have to implement that as well.

Check this for more info:
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour)

Comment: I referred this post. I have implement UINAvigationCOntroller and UITabBarController's Category class with shouldAutoRotate and other necessary methods. But still no result.