# IOS - Rotate Mpmovieplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` in `UITabbarcontroller` and I don't know why it doesn't auto rotate

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [dt objectForKey:@"TrailerPath"]];

moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
    moviePlayer.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    moviePlayer.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);        
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Woah dude, where can I get rats in movie players? Let me know! Favorited :-)

Comment: Thank for your reply,now i fix interface of the iphone is portrait in Summary, and i'm still wanna show landsacpe when playing video,how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you setup supported interface orientations for your project, in project settings?

**EDIT:** You can set supported interface orientations here: [image]

Comment: I don't know what can i do, can you explain more detail for it?

Comment: right, i'm fix interface only portrait, when playing video need to lanscape

Comment: Ok, look at my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526054/autorotate-in-ios-6-has-strange-behaviour/12538622

I had the same problem

Comment: Yes, see answer in that question

Comment: thank @Tim, can you help me once more time, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475673/ios-login-view-before-uitabbarcontroller/14476067#14476067

Comment: hi @time, i'm using code like - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}, but MPMoviePlayer still rotate