# iOS - login view before uitabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbar, mpmovieplayer

I want to display interface `UITabBar` when login succeeds.
I declare interface `UITabBar` in `AppDelegate`, but after login success I don't know how to call the interface.

Here is my code:

appdelegate.m

```
    -(void)loadInterface
{
    [self configureiPhoneTabBar];
}

    -(void)configureiPhoneTabBar
    {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UIViewController *controller1 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"home_ON.png" : @"home.png" andText:@"Trang chủ" forViewController:controller1];

        UIViewController *controller2 = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
        [self configureTabBarItemWithImageName:@"channel_ON.png" : @"tvChannel.png" andText:@"Kênh" forViewController:controller2];
    }
```

and `loginviewcontroller.m`

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idenLogin" sender:self];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate loadInterface];
}
```

Secondly, when you touch on button "play", layout video shows and it works ok, but I want to auto rotate

note: This is interface on iphone and I fix Portrait in Summary, I'm still show landscape, How to do?

Can u download [my code demo is here](http://www.mediafire.com/?z2aqnd08tz9lbj8)

Comment: I would fix iso to ios first :)

Answer (score 0):

in couple of words you need modal view for login screen.

Here is how I did it (from app delegate class). Note that I have my login view designed in storytboard.

```
- (void) showLoginView
{
        assert(loginController == nil);
        assert(activityView == nil);

        UITabBarController *tabbar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        loginController = [tabbar.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        loginController.delegate = self;
        [tabbar presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create an object in my AppDelegate called WindowState or similar that manages what should be the rootViewController of the window. Initially it would be a sign in or splash, then you can run checks in your WindowState class and listen for notifications eg. MyAppDidSignInNotification then change the rootViewController of your app to a UITabBarController or whatever there.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.windowState = [[FASWindowState alloc] initWithWindow:self.window];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: sorry but ... it is not right if I do it instead of you :) Any help yes - but edit your code - no

Comment: right, i know it, but i don't understand your code ->[[FASWindowState alloc] initWithWindow:self.window];