# Iphone landscape and portrait issue

Tags: iphone

I m working on one application in which i have splash screen and home screen. My Application is landscape and portrait mode application. **When my application starts and i am on Landscape mode my home screen shows portrait mode for some mili seconds  and after that it comes into the landscape mode.** I want it should directly show the view in landscape mode.

Thanks

Comment: Had similar problem, solved with this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10146270/894671

Answer (score 0):

I usually enable notifications:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

On my controllers i put:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{      
    [self configureOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (void)configureOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{  

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsValidInterfaceOrientation(orientation)){

        if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)){
            [self configureLandscapelView];
        }else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
            [self configurePortraitlView];
        }
    } 
}
```

You can also get the orientation from the UIViewController itself:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [self interfaceOrientation];
```

Or from the status bar:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```