# UITabbarController different Orientation for each view controller

Tags: ios5, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

The problem is very simple.
I have a UITabbarcontroller set as a rootviewcontroller. 
UITabbarcontroller contains 2 viewcontrollers

1. firstViewcontroller (portarit)
2. secondViewController (landscape)

the problem is when i select second view controller the view and the tabar is not presented in landscape until or unless I change the orientation myself and vice versa for the firstviewcontroller.

Need to know the possible steps to make it achievable.

Important thing...

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
```

above method is only called when the device is rotated. so it works well for manual rotation but upon tabbar item selection. It actually doesn't do anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953351/iphone-landscape-faq-and-solutions